# Passar endereço variável de um função a outra

Tags: c, funções, variáveis, ponteiro

Como manipular corretamente o valor de uma variável que passa por referência de uma função em C.

Deixo um exemplo que demonstra minha questão:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void funcao2(int *var_versao2){
printf("%d",*var_versao2);
}

char funcao1(int *var){
 funcao2(*var);
}

int main(){
int valor;
scanf("%d", &valor);

funcao1(&valor);

return 0;
}
```

Como já é de se esperar, o código acima está incorreto na hora de passar a variável da `funcao1()` para a `funcao2()`, entretanto eu não descobri como fazer isso.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Deixando de lado o fato que isso não é necessário, considerando que é apenas um exemplo do mecanismo, comece entender oque está escrevendo de fato.

Provavelmente está achando que o `*` é um operador que faz alguma coisa na declaração do tipo da variável, o que ele não é. Ele é um operador dentro do código, mas não na declaração de tipo.

Um coisa que facilitaria muito as pessoas entenderem é se fosse algo por extenso em vez de usar um símbolo. Quando você tem um `int *` leia como `pointer of int`.

Então entenda que isso é o tipo que está declarando. O tipo não é `int` e tem um operador manipulando a variável, o tipo é `int *` (ou *pointer of int*). A variável não guarda um valor inteiro ali, ele guarda um ponteiro para um valor inteiro, portanto o que é guardado é um ponteiro.

Algumas pessoas preferem escrever assim: `int* var` para deixar mais claro que o tipo é uma coisa só. O jeito que a maioria escreve dá a impressão que o asterisco está operando a variável, que na verdade está sendo só declarada.

Outro ponto importante é que a declaração de um parâmetro é a mesma coisa que declarar uma variável local.

Então se `var` é um ponteiro, e logo em seguida vai passar como argumento para uma função que espera um ponteiro, porque está  o `*` na passagem do argumento? Você já tem o que quer passar, só passe aquilo, não tente manipular aquilo.

É diferente quando vai passar o `valor` que preciso usar um operador, porque a função está esperando um ponteiro e você não tem um ali, o operador `&` cria um ponteiro para aquele valor.

Quando passa para o `printf()` usa o operador `*`, justamente porque esse operador pega um valor que está apontado, ou seja, você não quer imprimir o ponteiro que é o que você tem na variável, quer imprimir o valor apontado, por isso precisa dizer isso, precisa manipular o valor para entregar o que quer, da mesma forma que você aria uma adição se esse fosse o objetivo.

Ainda tinha um outro erro que a função não está retornando nada mas tem um tipo de retorno.

Consertando e organizando:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void funcao2(int *var) {
    printf("%d", *var);
}

void funcao1(int *var) {
    funcao2(var);
}

int main() {
    int valor;
    scanf("%d", &valor);
    funcao1(&valor);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/s2jFrL). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/yqwejaueud-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/DeclarationParam.c).